# Merge new row into an existing xts ( purpose: to add current stock quote to historical object from quantmod)

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

What I like to do is to get and attach current stock price to an historical xts object. example,

```
require(quantmod)
x=getSymbols("AAPL", from = "2014-10-27" ,auto.assign=FALSE)
q = getQuote('AAPL')

# this produces, > tail(x)
           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
2015-05-06    126.56    126.75   123.36     125.01    72141000        124.49
2015-05-07    124.77    126.08   124.02     125.26    43940900        125.26
2015-05-08    126.68    127.62   126.11     127.62    55550400        127.62
2015-05-11    127.39    127.56   125.63     126.32    42035800        126.32
2015-05-12    125.60    126.88   124.82     125.87    47109200        125.87
2015-05-13    126.15    127.19   125.87     126.01    34322000        126.01
> q
              Trade Time     Last Change % Change   Open   High    Low   Volume
AAPL 2015-05-14 11:38:00 128.3993 2.3893 +1.8961% 127.45 128.45 127.16 22635316
```

What I like to do is place the "Last" column from q as the AAPL.Close column, High & Low into AAPL.High, AAPL.Close, respectively.   I have tried so far to create a new dataframe by slowly adding in new columns, renaming them and merging back onto the original xts but it does not appear to work.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create a new xts object from the quote data and `rbind` it to the historical data.

```
require(quantmod)
x <- getSymbols("AAPL", from = "2014-10-27" ,auto.assign=FALSE)
q <- getQuote('AAPL')

qCols <- c("Open","High","Low","Last","Volume","Last")
qx <- xts(q[,qCols], as.Date(q[,"Trade Time"]))
y <- rbind(x, qx)

tail(y)
#            AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
# 2015-05-07    124.77    126.08   124.02     125.26    43940900        125.26
# 2015-05-08    126.68    127.62   126.11     127.62    55550400        127.62
# 2015-05-11    127.39    127.56   125.63     126.32    42035800        126.32
# 2015-05-12    125.60    126.88   124.82     125.87    47109200        125.87
# 2015-05-13    126.15    127.19   125.87     126.01    34322000        126.01
# 2015-05-14    127.45    128.45   127.16     128.40    22635316        128.40
```

Comment: thank you.  this was clear and I learned from it so extra bonus.  I found a couple of minor mistakes in the qx line, `qx <- xts(q[,qCols], as.Date(q[,"Trade Time"])  )`  Also are u the author of the TTR and xts packages, if so just wanted to say I feel privileged chatting.  heh.

Comment: @Ahdee: sorry about the typos. Yes, I'm that guy. :) I'm glad you find the packages useful!

Answer (score 1):

getQuote returns the last transaction time as well as date.  If you need to capture this time as well as the date, you might try something like

```
require(quantmod)
ticker <- "AAPL"
x <- getSymbols(ticker, from = "2014-10-27" ,auto.assign=FALSE)
q  <-  getQuote(ticker)
mkt_close_time <- "16:00:00"
index(x) <- strptime(paste(index(x),mkt_close_time), format="%F %X", tz="EST5EDT")
x <- rbind(x,xts( with(q, data.frame(Open, High, Low, Last, Volume, Last)),
                  order.by=strptime(q$"Trade Time", format="%F %X", tz="EST5EDT")))
```