# How to solve an error of calculated variable after adding new trade row into quantmod data set?

Tags: r, quantmod

I used a code (link is attached) to add new row of trade data into the data set:

```
 gspc<-getSymbols(("^GSPC") , src = 'yahoo', from = '2008-01-01',  auto.assign = T)
    gspc<-cbind(GSPC)
    q <- getQuote("^GSPC") # adds the current trade row
    qCols <- c("Open","High","Low","Last","Volume","Last")
    qx <- xts(q[,qCols], as.Date(q[,"Trade Time"]))
    gspc <- rbind(gspc, qx)
```

I got a fine output:

```
tail(gspc)

               GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close GSPC.Volume GSPC.Adjusted GSPCIsuP GSPCIsUp1day GSPCOpAbOp GSPCMA5Op GSPCMA5High GSPCHiLo1d GSPCMAHiLo5d GSPCSTdVHiLo5d GSPCMaOpCl5d GSPCMA10Op
2015-11-03   2102.63   2116.48  2097.51    2109.79  4272060000       2109.79        1            1  21.869873  2085.644    2090.752  25.439941     11.88403      11.720686    -6.943994   2068.559
2015-11-04   2110.60   2114.59  2096.98    2102.31  4078870000       2102.31        0            1   7.970215  2094.468    2099.974  13.850097     14.33003      10.223758    -8.948047   2076.272
2015-11-05   2101.68   2108.78  2090.41    2099.93  4051890000       2099.93        0            0  -8.920166  2097.134    2104.822   3.989990     10.35400       9.420192    -2.516015   2084.252
2015-11-06   2098.60   2101.91  2083.74    2099.20  4369020000       2099.20        1            0  -3.079834  2098.854    2108.074   7.100097     10.94004       9.022028    -1.954053   2088.293
2015-11-09   2096.56   2096.56  2068.24    2078.58  3882350000       2078.58        0            0  -2.040039  2102.014    2109.592   3.309814     10.73799       9.216563    -4.202002   2090.441
2015-11-10   2077.19   2077.98  2073.35    2077.12    34835429       2077.12       NA           NA         NA        NA          NA         NA           NA             NA           NA         NA
```

But when I tried to add two calculated fields, the first one worked fine but the other produce an error

```
gspc$GSPCHiLo1d<-Lag(Hi(GSPC),k=1)-Lag(Op(GSPC),k=1) # that's fine
gspc$GSPCMAHiLo10d<-SMA(gspc$GSPCHiLo1d,n=10)
#I got an error "Error in runSum(x, n) : Series contains non-leading NAs"
```

How can I overcome this problem? 
link to the code I used:
[source code link for adding new row to quantmod data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241932/merge-new-row-into-an-existing-xts-purpose-to-add-current-stock-quote-to-hist)

Comment: Check your variable `GSPCHiLo1d`. If there is a `NA` value in the variable (at the exception of the beginning of it), then the error is returned

Comment: Hello @etienne yes It does, but I can't eliminate it from the data set, so i'm looking for a way to let the second variable to ignor the NA of the first variable and still to preduce the calculation

Comment: When I ran this code without adding the new row: gspc<-getSymbols(("^GSPC") , src = 'yahoo', from = '2008-01-01', auto.assign = T)
gspc<-cbind(GSPC) both variables worked fine

Comment: What is `q` in your code ? the variable isn't defined

Comment: My bad, I added the line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your last line with :

```
gspc$GSPCMAHiLo10d<-SMA(gspc$GSPCHiLo1d[-nrow(gspc)]) # the n=10 is optional as it is the default option

tail(gspc)
           GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close GSPC.Volume GSPC.Adjusted GSPCHiLo1d GSPCMAHiLo10d
2015-11-03   2102.63   2116.48  2097.51    2109.79  4272060000       2109.79  25.439941     12.483997
2015-11-04   2110.60   2114.59  2096.98    2102.31  4078870000       2102.31  13.850097     13.270007
2015-11-05   2101.68   2108.78  2090.41    2099.93  4051890000       2099.93   3.989990     13.219006
2015-11-06   2098.60   2101.91  2083.74    2099.20  4369020000       2099.20   7.100097     10.597021
2015-11-09   2096.56   2096.56  2068.24    2078.58  3882350000       2078.58   3.309814      8.772998
2015-11-09   2096.56   2096.56  2068.24    2078.58   664847995       2078.58         NA            NA
```

as you can see it will put a `NA` in your last cell at the bottom right. The thing is, your formula with the two `Lag` is shorter by one element from `gspc` so the last element is a `NA` which will cause a problem for your calculations. After running the command `SMA` you can (if you want) replace the `NA` values.

You can also replace the last value of `gspc$GSPCHiLo1d` with what you want and then run the `SMA` command without problem.

Ok I think I found one of the problem : use

```
gspc$GSPCHiLo1d<-Lag(Hi(gspc),k=1)-Lag(Op(gspc),k=1)
```

instead of

```
gspc$GSPCHiLo1d<-Lag(Hi(GSPC),k=1)-Lag(Op(GSPC),k=1)
```

and then

```
gspc$GSPCMAHiLo10d<-SMA(gspc$GSPCHiLo1d,n=10)

tail(gspc)
           GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close GSPC.Volume GSPC.Adjusted GSPCHiLo1d
2015-11-03   2102.63   2116.48  2097.51    2109.79  4272060000       2109.79  25.439941
2015-11-04   2110.60   2114.59  2096.98    2102.31  4078870000       2102.31  13.850097
2015-11-05   2101.68   2108.78  2090.41    2099.93  4051890000       2099.93   3.989990
2015-11-06   2098.60   2101.91  2083.74    2099.20  4369020000       2099.20   7.100097
2015-11-09   2096.56   2096.56  2068.24    2078.58  3882350000       2078.58   3.309814
2015-11-10   2077.19   2079.70  2069.91    2071.69   109144559       2071.69   0.000000
           GSPCMAHiLo10d
2015-11-03     12.483997
2015-11-04     13.270007
2015-11-05     13.219006
2015-11-06     10.597021
2015-11-09      8.772998
2015-11-10      8.767016
```

from your comment you want `High` - `Low` but in your code it is `High` - `Open`. Replace`Op` by `Lo` and you will have

```
tail(gspc)
           GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close GSPC.Volume GSPC.Adjusted GSPCHiLo1d
2015-11-03   2102.63   2116.48  2097.51    2109.79  4272060000       2109.79   25.43994
2015-11-04   2110.60   2114.59  2096.98    2102.31  4078870000       2102.31   18.96997
2015-11-05   2101.68   2108.78  2090.41    2099.93  4051890000       2099.93   17.61011
2015-11-06   2098.60   2101.91  2083.74    2099.20  4369020000       2099.20   18.37012
2015-11-09   2096.56   2096.56  2068.24    2078.58  3882350000       2078.58   18.16992
2015-11-10   2077.19   2079.70  2069.91    2071.01   110450050       2071.01   28.32007
           GSPCMAHiLo10d
2015-11-03      18.58199
2015-11-04      19.22799
2015-11-05      18.91400
2015-11-06      17.41902
2015-11-09      17.08101
2015-11-10      19.05203
```

with the desired 28.32

If that is not what you wanted then please tell me

Comment: What should I do if I have a calculation that invovles 50 days history and I would like to ignore the NA that it produces? I tried: gspc$GSPCMAHiLo10d<-SMA(gspc$GSPCHiLo1d[-nrow(gspc[1:50,])],n=50) but it was wrong.

Comment: try `SMA(gspc$GSPCHiLo1d[-((nrow(gspc)-49):nrow(gspc))],n=50)`. Of course the missing values will be replaced by `NA` in the output. EDIT : probably 49 instead of 50

Comment: I tried the code but got  Error:Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: The above is quite ugly. Better use : `SMA(head(gspc$GSPCHiLo1d,-50),n=50)`

Comment: Your error is because your variable `gspc$GSPCMAHiLo10d` already exists and the code creates a shorter variable.

Comment: I think that there is a misunderstanding in regards that the new  row (here it's 2015-11-09 ) gets the NA while it has to contain values that will be part of a classification model.So how can I  invert the results that the first old row will be with NA and the current day row will be with the calculated values?

Comment: The first date (2008-01-02 in my data set) .I need to get the valusf of the variables that are related to the new current row (2015-11-09) and apply them on a glm predict function.

Comment: I change the data in my q to better fit the problem: I got today's last trade data and for my prediction I would need the last day values on the current row (today : 2015-11-10) so as for the column  GSPCHiLo1d I would need: GSPC.High  - GSPC.Low of 2015-11-09 which is 2096.56  - 2068.24 so the output for this field  for the current 2015-10-09 row is 28.32